# MetaClass couldn't create public edu.stanford.nlp.time.TimeExpressionExtractorImpl(java.lang.String,java.util.Properties) with args [sutime, {}]

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

I am using the method described on the stanford CoreNLP page [here.](http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/cmdline.html#classpath)

In order to run Stanford CoreNLP from the command line the following command is used :

```
java -cp "*" -Xmx2g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,parse,dcoref -file input.txt
```

I have run this command from the distribution directory. However. I am getting the following error :

```
Exception in thread "main" edu.stanford.nlp.util.ReflectionLoading$ReflectionLoadingException: Error creating edu.stanford.nlp.time.TimeExpressionExtractorImpl
    at edu.stanford.nlp.util.ReflectionLoading.loadByReflection(ReflectionLoading.java:40)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.time.TimeExpressionExtractorFactory.create(TimeExpressionExtractorFactory.java:57)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.time.TimeExpressionExtractorFactory.createExtractor(TimeExpressionExtractorFactory.java:38)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.regexp.NumberSequenceClassifier.<init>(NumberSequenceClassifier.java:86)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.NERClassifierCombiner.<init>(NERClassifierCombiner.java:136)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorImplementations.ner(AnnotatorImplementations.java:121)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorFactories$6.create(AnnotatorFactories.java:273)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorPool.get(AnnotatorPool.java:152)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.construct(StanfordCoreNLP.java:451)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:154)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:150)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:137)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.main(StanfordCoreNLP.java:1323)
Caused by: edu.stanford.nlp.util.MetaClass$ClassCreationException: MetaClass couldn't create public edu.stanford.nlp.time.TimeExpressionExtractorImpl(java.lang.String,java.util.Properties) with args [sutime, {}]
    at edu.stanford.nlp.util.MetaClass$ClassFactory.createInstance(MetaClass.java:237)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.util.MetaClass.createInstance(MetaClass.java:382)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.util.ReflectionLoading.loadByReflection(ReflectionLoading.java:38)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:466)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.util.MetaClass$ClassFactory.createInstance(MetaClass.java:233)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
    at de.jollyday.util.CalendarUtil.<init>(CalendarUtil.java:42)
    at de.jollyday.HolidayManager.<init>(HolidayManager.java:66)
    at de.jollyday.impl.DefaultHolidayManager.<init>(DefaultHolidayManager.java:46)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.time.JollyDayHolidays$MyXMLManager.<init>(JollyDayHolidays.java:148)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:466)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:556)
    at de.jollyday.caching.HolidayManagerValueHandler.instantiateManagerImpl(HolidayManagerValueHandler.java:60)
    at de.jollyday.caching.HolidayManagerValueHandler.createValue(HolidayManagerValueHandler.java:41)
    at de.jollyday.caching.HolidayManagerValueHandler.createValue(HolidayManagerValueHandler.java:13)
    at de.jollyday.util.Cache.get(Cache.java:51)
    at de.jollyday.HolidayManager.createManager(HolidayManager.java:168)
    at de.jollyday.HolidayManager.getInstance(HolidayManager.java:148)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.time.JollyDayHolidays.init(JollyDayHolidays.java:57)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.time.Options.<init>(Options.java:90)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.time.TimeExpressionExtractorImpl.init(TimeExpressionExtractorImpl.java:44)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.time.TimeExpressionExtractorImpl.<init>(TimeExpressionExtractorImpl.java:39)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:532)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:186)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:473)
    ... 38 more
```

My java version is 1.9 and the CoreNLP which I have downloaded is the latest one,i.e.  3.7.0.

Also, I do not have multiple versions of Stanford CoreNLP installed. Is this problem in the version? Where could I be going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I downloaded the distribution folder from here: http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/download.html

I unzipped it and cd'd into stanford-corenlp-full-2016-10-31

I entered this command:

```
java -cp "*" -Xmx2g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,parse,dcoref -file input.txt -outputFormat text
```

And it worked properly.  Did you add extra jars to the folder?  What type of system are you running this on?

I am running with Java 1.8 and as far as I know Java 1.9 has not been released yet, so that could be an issue as well.

Comment: Yes. The issue was with Java 1.9. It worked well with Java 1.8. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

If you will work with **Java 9**, you should be able to use this command:

```
java -cp "*" -Xmx2g --add-modules java.xml.bind edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,parse,dcoref -file input.txt -outputFormat text
```

Note the use of `--add-modules java.xml.bind`, this option allow you solve the error  NoClassDefFoundError:javax/xml/bind/JAXBException.

Answer (score 1):

This fixed it for me, adding this to the props:

```
props.setProperty("ner.useSUTime", "0");
```

As explained here: https://github.com/sergey-tihon/Stanford.NLP.NET/issues/11